# ggplot not graphing in

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been looking at this for a while now, does anyone see anything wrong with this ggplot syntax? I am getting this error:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

this is z:

```
     Month Value
1  2011-01-01    11
2  2011-02-01     5
3  2011-03-01     6
4  2011-04-01     6
5  2011-05-01     4
6  2011-06-01     5
7  2011-07-01     3
8  2011-08-01     9
9  2011-09-01    19
10 2011-10-01     3
11 2011-11-01     6
12 2011-12-01     2
13 2012-01-01     1
14 2012-02-01     4
15 2012-04-01     1
16 2012-05-01     2
17 2012-06-01    11
18 2012-07-01     5


ggplot(z, aes(Month, Value)) + 
  geom_bar(fill="orange",size=.3)  + 
  theme_bw() + scale_x_discrete(name="Date") +   
  scale_y_continuous("Number") +
  opts(title="Monthly issues", 
       axis.title.x = theme_text(face="bold", colour="#990000"), 
       axis.text.x  = theme_text(angle=90), 
       axis.title.y = theme_text(face="bold", colour="#990000", angle=90)
   ) + 
  geom_smooth(data=z,aes(Month,Value,group=1), method="lm", size=2, color="darkblue")
```

Comment: It runs fine for me and produces a plot just fine. Check `str(z)` and make sure that you don't have `Value` stored as a factor.

Comment: this is the output of str(z):  str(z)
'data.frame':   18 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Month: Date, format: "2011-01-01" "2011-02-01" "2011-03-01" "2011-04-01" ...
 $ Value: num  11 5 6 6 4 5 3 9 19 3 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha! The problem is your `Month` column, which as you note in your comment is stored as a Date. R considers this a continuous variable, hence the error with `scale_x_discrete`. You should probably convert it to a character with `as.character` if you want to use it with `geom_bar`.

Comment: yes when I did this z$Month<-as.Character(z$Month), I can manually run and I see the graph. Problem is that when I try to run this line of code in an R script, my images are not populated: png(paste(m,"-","Issues",".png",sep=""), height=700, width=650) and that ggplot command and dev.off(), png files are created but they are empty.

Comment: @MikeDude That's an entirely different problem that is so common it is a [FAQ](http://cran.at.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f).

Comment: thank you so much. That was a great catch (as.character). I was finally able to get around the image generation by  grid.arrange, not sure better ways but, this will do it for me.